# Set custom default Location and Comment in Printer Properties?

Tags: printer, properties

This might be an eclectic question, but is there a way to change the default "Location" and "Comment" in printer properties?

I work at a tech place and troubleshoot many various printers. By default, each new printer I test, these fields are blank, and I need to re-type the Location and Comment for each printer that passes QA. I'm hoping there's a registry entry or something that could help with this.

Thanks!

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This information should be in the registry under the key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Printers\PRINTER-NAME`

The values are named :

- `Description` for `Comment`
- `Location` for itself